# ipcMain y ipcRenderer no trabajan

Tags: nodejs, electron

estoy haciendo un curso de electron JS pero cuando uso ipcMain y ipcRenderer no trabajan.

**index.js**
Este es el index.js en donde la applicacion inicia

```
ipcMain.on('product:new', (e, newProduct) => {
/*mainWindow.webContents.send('product:new', newProduct);
newProductWindow.close();*/
console.log(newProduct);
});
```

**new-product.html**

La vista donde está el formulario para mandar los productos a otro lado

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>Add new products</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/3/slate/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <form class="p-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Product's Name" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="Price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Save Product
        </button>
    </form>
    
    <script>

        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron'); // Es un protocolo para la comunicación entre ventanas

        const form = document.querySelector('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();


            const nameProduct = document.querySelector('#name').value;
            const priceProduct = document.querySelector('#price').value;
            const descProduct = document.querySelector('#description').value;

            const newProduct = {
                name: nameProduct,
                price: priceProduct,
                description: descProduct
            }; // Preparamos el objeto para mandar los datos a otra vista

            ipcRenderer.send('product:new', newProduct); // Mandamos
            // Los datos a la vista
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Necesito ayuda, no logro mandar los datos de ese formulario a la vista principal usando ipcRenderer y main. Solo eso necesita necesito

> Lograr mandas los datos de ese formulario a otra ventana usando esos protocolos

Answer (score 0):

La solución es que en el index.js hay que especificar que queremos disponible los comandos y librerias que ofrece nodeJS

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: { // Aqui especificamos
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```